# in_array for PHP not working

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays, DefaultSizes and ExistingSizes that I retrieved from the database.
$DefaultSizes have values 'L','M', 'S' and $ExistingSizes has 'S'. (Ran a foreach look to check through the values for both of them)

I want to print out values in $DefaultSizes that are not in $ExistingSizes.

This is my code:

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($DefaultSizes as &$def)
{
    if(in_array($def['Size'],$ExistingSizes) === false)
    {
        echo "$def[Size]<br>";
        $count++;
    }
}
```

The value 'S' still gets printed out.

Comment: array_diff is a php function which will give you the difference of two arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `in_array`. Use `array_diff` and shorten your code:

```
$DefaultSizes = ['L','M','S'];
$ExistingSizes = ['S'];
$not_in_existing = array_diff($DefaultSizes, $ExistingSizes);
print_r($not_in_existing);  // array('L', 'M')
```

Comment: Hi, i changed my codes to

$not_in_existing = array_diff($DefaultSizes, $ExistingSizes);
print_r($not_in_existing);

but there's an error "Array to string conversion" on the array_diff line.

Comment: My arrays are fetched from database. and stored into the array using :     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $DefaultSizes[] = $row;
  }
Is this the issue?

Comment: `Print_r($DefaultSizes)`. It is multidimensional?. If yes - you need to make it one dimension.

Comment: It is not. I used "Select Size from Sizes" for my sql query so there is only the column 'Size' inside it.

Comment: It is. And if you print it - you will see. To make it one dimension you should do `$DefaultSizes[] = $row[0];` or something like that.